# Exchange Server Organizational Structure

Tags: resources, build, exchange-server, hierarchy

I need to figure out a way to build a hierarchy by Director->Manager->Employee from an exchange server.  I have very limited knowledge of exchange, so does anyone have any ideas for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of that may help here is the manager attribute in AD.

To build a proper hierarchy based upon the manager settings may require some coding.

I can't understand what you are trying to achieve in Exchange.